# asp.net/vb.net - system.net smtp mail not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, ssl, tls1.2

So I have an smtp mail setup that has recently stopped working.

what happens is the code runs from an iframe that's on another domain. but the iframe is on the same domain as the smtp email.

for example:

```
Main Site --> www.mysite.com
   Iframe --> www.myiframe.com
```

On the iframe server the smtp is setup using system.net and worked until recently. the smtp server is with goddady on office365 the code looks like this:

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="me@mysite.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.office365.com" userName="me@mysite.com" password="password" defaultCredentials="true" port="587" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

What I have noticed is that I recently had to change all my emails from SSL to TLS in order for them to work on 587. I have also tested these smtp settings on my php server and they work fine but with one key difference. I have to define TLS instead of SSL with SSL I get a failed authentication response.

What I think might be happening is although `enablessl` is enabled & is supposed to also support TLS its not bothering with TLS and is just going SSL and failing and that's that.

Does anyone know of a way to force TLS in system.net or perhaps a reason for the recent bug.

As requested via comments:

```
 Private Sub SendEmail()
    Try
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        Dim Recipient As String = Request("e").ToString()
        Dim name As String = Request("n").ToString()
        Dim body As String = File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DataRoot") & "email.txt").Replace("[firstname]", name)
        Dim msg As New MailMessage()
        msg.From = New MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConfirmEmailFrom"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConfirmEmailFromName"))
        msg.To.Add(New MailAddress(Recipient, name))
        msg.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConfirmEmailSubject")
        msg.Body = body
        smtp.Send(msg)
    Catch ex As Exception
        siteMessage.LogMessage("Failed sending confirmation email to " & Request("e").ToString(), ex, Nothing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: can you share your code? you have shared the config section.

Comment: @KaushalKumarPanday done

Answer (score 1):

In **System.Net** you can enforce TLS version as shown below (**C#**):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

However this is dependent on the underlying .NET framework version your application is using. The support for **TLS v1.2** is available in **.NET 4.5 and above**.

Here is the MSDN documentation for this: [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In the **SmtpClient** class there is nothing apart from the **EnableSsl** property which you have already enabled via config.